# How can I easily compress and decompress files using zlib?

Tags: c++, zlib, compression

How can I easily compress and decompress files using zlib?

Comment: Have you read the [zlib](http://zlib.net/manual.html) [documentation](http://zlib.net/zlib_how.html)? If so, what have you tried? If what you tried didn't work, then post your code and say what happened.

Answer (score 18):

For decompression:

```
char buf[1024*1024*16];
gzFile *fi = (gzFile *)gzopen("file.gz","rb");
gzrewind(fi);
while(!gzeof(fi))
{
    int len = gzread(fi,buf,sizeof(buf));
        //buf contains len bytes of decompressed data
}
gzclose(fi);
```

For compression

```
gzFile *fi = (gzFile *)gzopen("file.gz","wb");
gzwrite(fi,"my decompressed data",strlen("my decompressed data"));
gzclose(fi);
```

Comment: @Cristi: I'm getting an error: `main.cpp invalid conversion from `const void*' to `void*'` on this line: `gzwrite(fi,"my decompressed data",strlen("my decompressed data"));`. Could you please help me?

Comment: try gzwrite(fi,(void const *)"my decompressed data",strlen("my decompressed data"));

Comment: @Cristi: I am getting the same error.

Comment: well it seems that in your zlib distribution gzwrite takes void * as second parameter instead of const void * as mine does. A quick bad fix would be gzwrite(fi,(void*)"my decompressed data",strlen("my decompressed data"));

Comment: @Cristi: Now I am getting: `[Linker error] undefined reference to 'gzopen'`.

Comment: if you are using visual studio you need to add the zlib .lib file to your project. In project properties: "configuration properties-> linker >general-> additional lib directories" add the folder path to the library and in "configuration properties-> linker >input-> additional dependencies" at the zlib lib file name.  The name of the zlib lib file name may vary according to your distribution. it may be zdll.lib if you link dynamically to zlib or zlib.lib for static linkage.

Comment: @Cristi: Okay, now the compressing is working, but the decompressing is not. `error C3861: 'gzrewind': identifier not found` And `error C3861: 'gzeof': identifier not found`.

Comment: I'm using zlib version 1.2.5, April 19th, 2010, what version are you using? You can find the version in zlib.h, if you have a old version can't you just update to the latest version? If not I guess you could try:
gzFile *fi = (gzFile *)gzopen("file.gz","rb");
int len=1;
while(len>0)
{
 len = gzread(fi,buf,sizeof(buf));
 //buf contains len bytes of decompressed data
}
gzclose(fi);
Not the code above is untested.

Comment: @cristi: Okay, I've upgraded my zlib.h, zdll.lib and zlib1.dll. Now I am getting the following error: `Unhandled exception at 0x00411707 in zlib2.exe: 0xC00000FD: Stack overflow.` Do i also need to upgrade other files?

Comment: make sure you do a clean rebuild and replace zlib1.dll located in the exe folder with the new one and it shoud work

Comment: @Cristi: I have the new version, 1.2.5. Could you make a package for me please? so I can download it?

Answer (score 1):

Please read through this. The information is already available [here](http://www.zlib.net/zlib_how.html):
That is the first link that shows up even on google.

Comment: I don't find the documentation very easy. Isn't there just a simple function like compress() decompress()?

Comment: @Downvoter: Care to explain why the downvote? The OP never mentioned in the Orginal Question that he/she did not understand the examples on zlib website. I provided link to those, whats wrong with that?

Comment: i'd say anyone who asks a question like this on SO should be pretty obvious that they already RTFM and still need help, I find the zlib "examples" to be very unhelpful myself, most of us arent trying to uncompress stdin, for example.

Comment: @Datoxalas Yes, there are in fact `compress()` and `uncompress()` functions provided by zlib. Have you even looked at the documentation?

Answer (score -1):

If you can use boost, I would recommend the boost iostreams API. See the
[boost iostreams tutorial](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/libs/iostreams/doc/tutorial/filter_usage.html).  It has support for GZIP and BZIP2 compressors and decompressors.