# zlib - compress a file using C

Tags: zlib, compression

I'm looking for some code such that I can compress a .txt file to a .gz file and then decmopress the .gz file to stdout.

I need to use zlib - trouble is, I can't really find anything to get started!

I've seen this:
[How can I easily compress and decompress files using zlib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5649030/how-can-i-easily-compress-and-decompress-files-using-zlib)
and this:
http://zlib.net/zlib_how.html

but it's not really helping me. If any zlib users out there have any code snippets, it would be most appreciated.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: The question you linked to has code samples in its answers. What exactly is it you don't understand about them?

Comment: I know the API is not easy, but take Zlib's full example and take time to understand it: http://zlib.net/zpipe.c

Comment: I tried compressing the example, but when I open the .gz file, all that appears is "my decompressed data" i.e. it doesn't appear to be compressed...

Comment: How did you 'open' it? With an archiver? Sure, it will decompress it for you and show the decompressed data. Call `cat your_file.gz` and see if it's uncompressed or garbage.

Comment: Actually, when I do cat, it's garbage. If I open it with vim, it uncompresses it for me. Thanks!

Comment: Found suitable code at: http://www.gamedev.net/page/resources/_/technical/game-programming/in-memory-data-compression-and-decompression-r2279 Thanks for all the help guys!

Comment: zlib_how.html is a detailed explanation of zpipe.c. If reading zlib.h, followed by reading zlib_how.html is not helping you get started, then I am at a loss. zpipe.c does almost exactly what you want. It would take very little modification. To make this a good question, you would need to post code with _what you have tried_, what happened, and why you think it didn't work.